# Stuck in bluetooth module HC-06

Tags: bluetooth

I have a problem with ATmode in this module. I want to change baud rate and device's name, so I using an app Android "Bluetooth SPP" to pair with module and send ATcommand, but it doesnt reply when I send AT, then I test by connect TX to RX pin and it reply any character I send. In this document http://www.mcu-turkey.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/HC-Serial-Bluetooth-Products-201104.pdf , it said "before paired, it is at the AT mode", I misunderstand it, why we can send ATcommand while don't pair device???

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you are trying to send an AT command over the RF link - this is not how it works.

You need a wired connection to the TX/RX pins on the module, and send the AT commands this way (this is how you can send AT commands before pairing)

Here is an example schematic:

[image]

Here is a run through of [connecting a HC06 to an Arduino nano](http://english.cxem.net/arduino/arduino4.php).

[image]

EDIT- if you are not planning to connect using a microcontroller, then you will need a USB to RS232 cable (TTL level). You can get them with the connectors to fit the header on the modules like [this one](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/1x-USB-2-0-TO-RS232-Converter-UART-TTL-Serial-CP2102-For-Arduino-UNO-ATMEGA-PIC-/390535254897?pt=UK_BOI_Electrical_Components_Supplies_ET&hash=item5aedb71371):

[image]

Comment: thank you for reply, I think it sounds right, but what is that wired connection? I have to make a rs232 module to connect it to my computer??

Comment: If you don't have a microcontroller, yes. I know there are USB->RS232 cables available on eBay, some purposely made for sending the AT commands. Something [like this](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/1x-USB-2-0-TO-RS232-Converter-UART-TTL-Serial-CP2102-For-Arduino-UNO-ATMEGA-PIC-/390535254897?pt=UK_BOI_Electrical_Components_Supplies_ET&hash=item5aedb71371)